# Internet connection very slow after Linksys configuration

Tags: networking, internet, linksys, slow-connection

We have this network setup

1. Server1 - DHCP server, Domain
   Controller, AD
2. Lease line for Internet connection
3. From lease line to Linksys router
   (we dont use wireless though)
4. From linksys to Netgear (24 port
   Switch) and vonage (VoIP)
5. Netgear to all our machines

We configured Linsys with the static IP and DNS server addresses our ISP gave and we have routed it correctly.

All our work machines are configured with

1. Get IP automatically
2. DNS server addresses our ISP gave

The problem is that none of the sites are getting opened promptly. It is taking around 5 minutes to load google.com. But we are able to ping all the sites.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the DNS check utility at http://www.grc.com/dns/benchmark.htm

> GRC's DNS Benchmark performs a detailed analysis and comparison of the operational performance and reliability of any set of up to 200 DNS nameservers (sometimes also called resolvers) at once. When the Benchmark is started in its default configuration, it identifies all DNS nameservers the user's system is currently configured to use and adds them to its built-in list of publicly available “alternative” nameservers. Each DNS nameserver in the benchmark list is carefully “characterized” to determine its suitability — to you — for your use as a DNS resolver. This characterization includes testing each nameserver for its “redirection” behavior: whether it returns an error for a bad domain request, or redirects a user's web browser to a commercial marketing-oriented page. While such behavior may be acceptable to some users, others may find this objectionable.

Answer (score 2):

could it be that you are attempting to send IPV6 dns requests ? - when these time out a V4 request is being sent ?

Comment: How can i cross-check it whether it is V6 or V4?

Comment: whats the client ? windows / linux ? - This is only a long shot, but id start be checking ipv6 is off on your client o/s and see if it helps. Try "network.dns.disableIPv6" on the about:config of firefox, if its firefox your using to open the sites. ?